# Matplotlib.pyplot not showing numbers on axes in Vscode

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, visual-studio-code, graph, jupyter-notebook

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Cn1W.png)

I am using Jupyter Notebooks in virual env in vscode. My os is ubuntu 20.04 . My matplotlib.pyplot doesn't show numbers on axes.Any solution for this?

Comment: The numbers are there, but they're black on top of the notebook's dark background. If you want to see them properly in the notebook, one workaround is to make the whole figure white by adding `plt.figure(facecolor='w')` before `plt.plot(...)`.

Comment: Please don't post images of code/data/error messages. Post the formatted text directly here on SO. You can edit your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70995801/edit).

Comment: if you save the image you see that they have a transparent background and the number and axes are black, you can change to a Light Theme